# WP7 + Web Based applications - Minimizing code duplication

Tags: silverlight, architecture, windows-phone-7

I'm starting to jump in to WP7 development and I have a few questions. My current background/experience is with ASP.NET. I'm new to Silverlight as a whole, so I have some questions regarding the architectural design of the application. I don't have experience with MVC, and it appears that Silverlight is based off of it. Is that true? To my original question:

Once the new developer tools come out, the app will have a SQL CE back end that, as a future release, will sync with SQL Azure. I'd also like to provide a web based application that performs the same functions, and interacts with the Azure database. I'm wondering how I should structure the app to minimize any code duplication.

I was thinking of using a generic n-tier architecture. UI > Business Layer > DAL (LinqToSql) > Sql. These classes could get re-used on the web too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silverlight is not really based on MVC. In fact, you can implement any architectural pattern as long as you fully understand its functionality. Most people prefer MVVM, which is similar to MVC, the only main difference is that the controller is replaced by the ViewModel that plays the role of an intermediary data link between the model and the view.

With the release of Mango, you will indeed have access to SQLCE. In your case, since you are planning on using specific interoperability layers, I would recommend building both applications in Silverlight with an intermediary web service that will communicate with the data storage (in your case it will be Azure). You win in two points:

1. You are using Silverlight, which means that you can use a similar codebase (with platform adjustments, of course) to deliver the same functionality.
2. The web service is app-independent. Therefore if you ever decide to build, let's say, an iOS application, you will be able to use the same communication layer without major changes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and I'll take that as an answer as it reaffirms some things I was thinking. My only note is that I want to have a copy of the database running locally on the device, so I will avoid hitting a web service in that case. However, it gets me further in my thinking. Thanks